# Android mouse simulator

Tags: android, mouseevent

I have an android running on my dev board. How can i simulate the mouse pointer in that?

I will have an application which sends the (x,y) coordinates to a running deamon. It should be able simulate a tap at the corresponding point on the touch screen.

Can anyone suggest the ideas and feasibility of this ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable suggestion. I am not so regular in this site, Can u please tell me where can I accept the answer. (I used to acknowledge/thank thru comments and had thought it was the way to)

Comment: I have done as u mentioned, for all the helpful answers. Hope it will help. You have given me an important suggestion, which otherwise would have been unnoticed by me. Thanks alot EboMike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate such events using [monkey tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html)

it supports running in daemon mode accepting commands, see details and samples in [android repository](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=tree;f=cmds/monkey)